# Cannot get CV completion score beyond 75%

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

My CV has a completion score of 75%. To finish it, I need to:

> - Entered a degree or institution for each education entry
> - Entered a valid time frame for each education entry
> - Entered technologies for each education entry

However, I don't have any formal education, so I can't do this. My CV is complete in the sense that I've filled in all the information that I can.

Is this score merely a widget to help me complete my CV? Or is it also displayed to employers when listing potential candidates and/or a factor in search algorithms and the like? If so, how can I get it to 100%?

---

The [2016 developer survey](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#developer-profile-education) mentions:

> 13% of respondents across the globe tell us they are only self-taught.

The number for "people without any formal education" is almost certainly higher than 13%, since some of the other options are "On the Job Training", "Other", and "Online Course" which also aren't a form of formal education (the raw data isn't available yet, so I can't check the exact number).

At any rate, my situation is hardly unique.

Comment: "I have a Master's degree in Business (focus in Nonaya) from Wottsamatta U."

Comment: I don't even have a high school diploma :( Does this mean I can't get a job/people won't like me... Wait, I don't think it's even legal for me to get a job :P

Comment: Only Jon Skeet can get to 100%, sometimes even more.

Comment: 100% CV completion means that you are dead.

Comment: @Zizouz212: better (?) yet - back in high school I had to take the [Kuder Occupational Interest Survey](http://psychology.wikia.com/wiki/Kuder_Occupational_Interest_Survey). To be considered "suitable" for a particular occupation one had to score 40 or above. My lowest score was 15, for "Priest or Clergyman" (Dang! As Robert Heinlein once put it, "It's lovely work, if you can stomach it" :-). But my *highest* score was 38, for "Computer Programmer".  I am therefore unsuited for employment of ANY SORT - and frankly I think I should be getting disability payments. But NOOOoooo....!!! :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis can I have regular fries with that?

Comment: I'm sure it's broken down into sub-categories these days, all the way from nomadic abacus-whittler down to senior PHP developer.

Comment: @MartinJames - in all truth, among the various jobs I've held I have never worked in the food preparation or food service sector, although I have (far too many times) been a client. Thus, sad to say - NO! :-)

Comment: @MartinJames - I only like working outdoors on nice days, when it's not too hot, not too humid, maybe with a breeze wafting gently through the trees, soft fluffy clouds drifting lazily across the sky... Unfortunately, along with a full-time software developer job we also farm - and I am, therefore, out in all kinds of weather, rain or shine (or snow, or sleet, or tornadoes...), dealing with equipment, dealing with animals, and in general dealing with a lot of...errrrrm...manure. :-) If I had the time I'd sue someone as this obviously ain't fair - but I'm too busy workin'...  :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis it's pretty rural round here too, so I have learned all about farming.  Essentially, it means going to the pub every day to fill in the time between cashing EC subsidy checks for not farming a surplus and leaving land fallow.

Comment: ..while, at the same time, renting out the fallow fields for solar power generation.

Comment: @MartinJames I see what you did there - nice!

Comment: LinkedIn have the same problem. It insist you need to have at least two jobs for completion. The whole "percentage completion" isn't a very useful concept imo.

Comment: @MartinJames - ah-ha! I *knew* there was something I was doing wrong..! :-)

Comment: Round here, 'silage' is nothing to do with stored fodder, it's the number of acres you have covered in silicon photovoltaic panels :)

Comment: @Tunaki Are you sure Jon Skeet can get to 100%? Because Jon Skeet tends to cause integer overflows where ever he goes..